# Creating a Raster of Road Distance to Point

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, raster-calculator, shortest-path

I am using QGIS 2.6. This question is in two related parts:

I'm trying to create a raster of travel time from one point to another point travelling via the road system. Each raster pixel will roughly represent the amount of time taken to get to a given point.

Could I do this as a function of the travel-time from a number of different points?  (I suppose I could using the raster calculator once I have the previous rasters.) I.e. I could estimate the total time per week if one travels to location A 5 times a week, location B 3 times a week and location C 1 time a  week.

Additionally, can one incorporate a time for a given distance to the road for points that are off-road (i.e. walking distance)? I.e. an amount per metre of ground to cover the distance to the road (taking the shortest distance possible.

Comment: can you clarify your question a bit. What is your input data? Do you want the shortest path from locations (points) to destonation (points/polygons) via roads? (lines) or do you want all possible shortest path from each cell on a raster to each other cells, while movement is restricted to a road-classified cells only?

Comment: As dof1985 said, we need more information. Your initial question sounds like a simple Euclidean distance map, but then you start mentioning time.

Comment: Hopefully that helps. I see why it was confusing; very badly written sorry.

Comment: Considering a single raster, you can only look at each cell being time from a single point. With multiple points, the time value for any given cell will be from the *nearest* point. And there's two ways to look at the time value of the raster - time required to cross that cell (cost raster), or time needed to get to that cell from some origin (a solution/distance raster). It sounds like you're trying to blend the two and use them at the same time. Plus you're looking at distances between two points using a road (path of cells) vs off a road (time increases per cell away from the road).